# How to do this Regex with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to bring up the value of "uploadFinish". I want to do it with a regular expression. The content is inside a huge html:

```
MORE HTML
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="I" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="https://" />


<meta name="medium" content="image" />
<meta property="og:type" content="" />



        <script type="application/ld+json">
            {"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"ImageObject","caption":"011 de 366\nMagali \ud83c\udf49 \n#magali #TurmadaMonica #illustration #ilustra\u00e7\u00e3o #art #drawing.","representativeOfPage":"http:\/\/schema.org\/True","uploadFinish":"2020-01-11T22:08:58","author":{"@type":"Person","alternateName":"@luis","mainEntityofPage":{"@type":"ProfilePage","@id":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/luis\/"}},"comment":[{"@type":"Comment","text":"\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e","author":{"@type":"Person","alternateName":"@katiagualtieri985","mainEntityofPage":{"@type":"ProfilePage","@id":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/katiagualtieri985\/"}}}],"commentCount":"1","contentLocation":{"@type":"Place","name":"Florian\u00f3polis, Santa Catarina","mainEntityofPage":{"@type":"CollectionPage","@id":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/explore\/locations\/213145014\/A-B-C-D\/"},"address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","addressLocality":"Florian\u00f3polis, Santa Catarina","addressCountry":{"@type":"Country","name":"BR"}}},"interactionStatistic":{"@type":"InteractionCounter","interactionType":{"@type":"LikeAction"},"userInteractionCount":"225"},"mainEntityofPage":{"@type":"ItemPage","@id":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/p\/XDFASDFSAD\/"},"description":"225 Me gusta, 1 comentarios - Lu\u00eds (@luasdf) en Example: &quot;011 de 366\nMagali \ud83c\udf49 \n#magali #TurmadaMonica #illustration #ilustra\u00e7\u00e3o #art #drawing.&quot;","name":"Lu\u00eds en example: \u201c011 de 366\nMagali \ud83c\udf49 \n#magali #TurmadaMonica #illustration #ilustra\u00e7\u00e3o #art #drawing.\u201d"}
        </script>


<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/p/B7MhI_XgtYm/" hreflang="x-default" />

MORE HTML
```

I was trying to put together the following regular expression but I didn't succeed:

```
.w+(.*)+S\w*(uploadFinish)\w*
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should use HTML & JSON parsers, not regex.

Comment: I'm doing a web scraping and It's the reason that I can't be change it.

Comment: You can use parsers with web scraping

Comment: But I don't want load a libraries for a data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to extract it with the regular expression you can use the *positive lookbehind*`(?<=PATTERN)`. It matches the text that follows the given pattern, without the pattern itself.

In this case, the pattern would be `"uploadFinish":"`.

Positive lookbehind should be followed by a pattern that would match everything up to the first quotation mark e.g. `[^"]*`

That will allow you to extract the value without the quotation marks.

Making the whole pattern:

```
(?<="uploadFinish":")[^"]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether you are web scraping or not, you should be treating JSON as JSON. Attempting to interpret JSON as text with RegEx will always end up failing.

Here is an example of retrieving the part of the JSON that you want.

```js
const jsonLdElement = document.querySelector("[type='application/ld+json']")
const jsonLd = JSON.parse(jsonLdElement.textContent)
console.log(jsonLd.uploadFinish)
console.log(jsonLd)
```

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "caption": "011 de 366\nMagali \ud83c\udf49 \n#magali #TurmadaMonica #illustration #ilustra\u00e7\u00e3o #art #drawing.",
    "representativeOfPage": "http:\/\/schema.org\/True",
    "uploadFinish": "2020-01-11T22:08:58",
    "author": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "alternateName": "@luis",
      "mainEntityofPage": {
        "@type": "ProfilePage",
        "@id": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/luis\/"
      }
    },
    "comment": [{
      "@type": "Comment",
      "text": "\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e\ud83d\udc9e",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "alternateName": "@katiagualtieri985",
        "mainEntityofPage": {
          "@type": "ProfilePage",
          "@id": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/katiagualtieri985\/"
        }
      }
    }],
    "commentCount": "1",
    "contentLocation": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "Florian\u00f3polis, Santa Catarina",
      "mainEntityofPage": {
        "@type": "CollectionPage",
        "@id": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/explore\/locations\/213145014\/A-B-C-D\/"
      },
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "Florian\u00f3polis, Santa Catarina",
        "addressCountry": {
          "@type": "Country",
          "name": "BR"
        }
      }
    },
    "interactionStatistic": {
      "@type": "InteractionCounter",
      "interactionType": {
        "@type": "LikeAction"
      },
      "userInteractionCount": "225"
    },
    "mainEntityofPage": {
      "@type": "ItemPage",
      "@id": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/p\/XDFASDFSAD\/"
    },
    "description": "225 Me gusta, 1 comentarios - Lu\u00eds (@luasdf) en Example: &quot;011 de 366\nMagali \ud83c\udf49 \n#magali #TurmadaMonica #illustration #ilustra\u00e7\u00e3o #art #drawing.&quot;",
    "name": "Lu\u00eds en example: \u201c011 de 366\nMagali \ud83c\udf49 \n#magali #TurmadaMonica #illustration #ilustra\u00e7\u00e3o #art #drawing.\u201d"
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the value is always enclosed in double quotes, then a simple expression like this will give you the value you need:

```
html.match(/"uploadFinish":"(.*?)"/)
```

Here `html` is the response body. The group `(.*?)` matches any characters but as few as possible so it will stop when a double quote is encountered.